# For a nullable joined column, is it better performance to do a outer join, or inner join to a "null" row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, null

For SQL query performance, what is the best way to handle a null column?

Let's say I have some data objects Person and Employer. A Person can have a reference to an Employer, but they can also be unemployed and that is indicated by having a null reference.

Is it better for DB performance do to a left outer join on that nullable EmployerId field, or do an inner join to a "null" Employer and then in the data retrieval code turn that "null" Employer into an actual null?

(I know this is a trivial example that follows but assume I have many tens of thousands of rows where outer joins start to significantly affect performance)

**Outer join on nullable column**

TABLE Person (PersonId, Name, EmployerId) *(EmployerId is nullable)*

```
(1, 'John Doe', 1)  
(2, 'Joe Smith', NULL)  
(3, 'Jane Doe', 2)
```

TABLE Employers (EmployerId, Name)

```
(1, 'Microsoft')  
(2, 'google')
```

QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM Person LEFT OUTER JOIN Employers ON Person.EmployerId = Employers.EmployerId

(1, 'John Doe', 1, 'Microsoft')  
(2, 'Joe Smith', NULL, NULL)  
(3, 'Jane Doe', 2, 'google')
```

Code doesn't have to do anything beyond the DB read.

**Inner join on "null" row**

TABLE Person (PersonId, Name, EmployerId) *(EmployerId is NOT nullable)*

```
(1, 'John Doe', 1)  
(2, 'Joe Smith', 0)  
(3, 'Jane Doe', 2)
```

TABLE Employers (EmployerId, Name)

```
(0, '{NULL}')  
(1, 'Microsoft')  
(2, 'google')
```

QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM Person INNER JOIN Employers ON Person.EmployerId = Employers.EmployerId

(1, 'John Doe', 1, 'Microsoft')  
(2, 'Joe Smith', 0, '{NULL}')  
(3, 'Jane Doe', 2, 'google')
```

Code must do DB read, then detect "{NULL}" and convert to null reference.

Comment: The second item is not an inner join.

Comment: @StingyJack, I just fixed those typos :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second version looks weird to me.  `NULL` means more like "value is missing" than it means "the corresponding record with NULL as an index".  If you were going to use the second version, then use some other value than `NULL`.

Typically, when a database engine supports outer joins, the algorithm is amazingly similar to the algorithm for inner joins.  If the database supports a nested loop inner join, or an index lookup inner join, or a hash-based inner join, or a marge-sort inner join, then it support the same algorithms for outer join.  The difference in performance would be more due to the larger result set for the outer join.

By the way, in your now modified second example, the effect is the same as an inner join.  The query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person INNER JOIN
     Employers
     ON Person.EmployerId = Employers.EmployerId
```

The `join` condition fails when either or both `EmployerId`s are `NULL`.  `NULL` fails all comparisons, except `is null`.  So, the second example will not fetch the employer record with `NULL` on it.

You can change the `on` condition to fix this.  Here are two ways:

```
     on (Person.EmployerId = Employers.EmployerId) or
        (Person.EmployerId is NULL and  Employers.EmployerId is null)

     on coalesce(Person.EmployerId, -1) = coalesce(Emlpoyers.EmployerId, -1)
```

Then the joins are no longer the same in the two cases.  And, these joins might perform quite differently from the first case.  In particular, `or` conditions and functions on columns impede the use of indexes for joins.

Comment: I'm seeing a big performance decrease when I switch from an inner join to an outer join (that is, Person LEFT OUTER JOIN Employers). In this case I want to return all Person rows regardless of if they reference an Employer. Is what you're saying is that it shouldn't make a difference?

Comment: He said it's similar, he didn't say it's the same.  The inner join will be faster, as the DB engine won't do any work for the NULL values (of course, since it's doing less work).  But your schema design is wrong, I think.  And certainly don't have a record called '{NULL}'; have the value set as 'Unemployed' or some such value (since you know it).  This link is a little over the top, but it discusses appropriate uses of NULL http://sqlmag.com/database-administration/null-data-warehouse

Comment: @ZaijiaN . . . Are the join conditions exactly the same?  If you are testing for `NULL` in the `on` clause, then that could have a big impact on the choice of join algorithm.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah, no change in ON clause. CPU time increases 27% when INNER is changed to LEFT OUTER.

Comment: So the takeaway is, that outer joins do decrease DB performance compared to an inner join, and perhaps the "inner join on 'null' row" strategy is going to be the most performant?

Comment: @ZaijiaN . . . And how many rows are returned by each query?  The additional resource usage could merely be the handling of additional rows returned by the outer join query as opposed to the inner join query.  By the way, if you include the actual execution plans in the question, then there will be more information to understand the performance difference.  Also, for a realistic example, I would assume that `personId` and `employerId` are primary keys in their respective tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff My situation is that the Person table has 30,000 rows, and Employer table has 1,000 rows, and i'm returning Person left join Employer for 30,000 rows. PersonId and EmployerId are primary keys.